# How to upload files to VPS using Java

Tags: java, upload, vps

So I have a VPS and would like to know how I can upload a file (images in particular) to the VPS using Java. What do I need to install on the VPS and how would I go about doing this?

My VPS is going to be CentOS.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use the [Apache Commons Net library](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/) to connect to your VPS using FTP.  You will need to install FTP on your VPS.  How you will go about installing FTP depends on what OS your VPS is running.

Comment: You will probably want to install vsftpd.  You can install it using the centos package manager.  A quick google reveals many guides for installing and configuring vsftpd on a centos machine.  You might want to start there.  Feel free to ask more specific questions if you get stuck.

Comment: What about the second part, how can I upload files to vsftpd using java?

Comment: The link above has a [link](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/examples/ftp/FTPClientExample.java) to example uses of the FTPClient class.